# Why are the three embedding results are so different from transformer models?

Tags: huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model, sentence-similarity, sentence-transformers

I want to get short text embedding from transformer models, so I had tested 3 ways to compute it. All 3 cases are using models from Huggingface Hub.

```
inputs = tokenizer(text, padding=True, return_tensors="pt")

def embedding_1(text):
    
    inputs = tokenizer(text, padding=True, return_tensors="pt")
    outputs = model(**inputs)
    output_tensors = outputs[1]
    output_numpy = output_tensors.detach().numpy()

    return output_numpy

def embedding_2(text):
    model_output = model(**inputs)
    token_embeddings = model_output[0]
    input_mask_expanded = inputs['attention_mask'].unsqueeze(-1).expand(token_embeddings.size()).float()
        return torch.sum(token_embeddings * input_mask_expanded, 1) / torch.clamp(input_mask_expanded.sum(1), min=1e-9)
```

Both methods use the Chinese models:

```
tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained("hfl/chinese-roberta-wwm-ext")
model = BertModel.from_pretrained("hfl/chinese-roberta-wwm-ext")
```

And the 3rd method directly uses the sentence transformer models (https://www.sbert.net/):

```
def embedding_3(text):
    model = SentenceTransformer('sentence-transformers/distiluse-base-multilingual-cased')
    embedding = model.encode(text)
    return embedding
```

Now I tested the similarities of '这个好' and several other sentences, and the results are below (based on cosine_similarity):

```
simi 1: 这个好 | 这个非常好: tensor([0.9844]) 
simi 2: 这个好 | 这个非常好: tensor([0.8641]) 
simi 3: 这个好 | 这个非常好: tensor([[0.8629]]) 


simi 1: 这个好 | 这个非常不好: tensor([0.9840]) 
simi 2: 这个好 | 这个非常不好: tensor([0.8403]) 
simi 3: 这个好 | 这个非常不好: tensor([[0.5878]]) 

simi 1: 这个好 | 他很傻: tensor([0.9737]) 
simi 2: 这个好 | 他很傻: tensor([0.7483]) 
simi 3: 这个好 | 他很傻: tensor([[0.3601]]) 

simi 1: 这个好 | 中国人民解放军: tensor([0.9171]) 
simi 2: 这个好 | 中国人民解放军: tensor([0.5162]) 
simi 3: 这个好 | 中国人民解放军: tensor([[0.0597]])
```

It's clear that the 3 methods produces very different similarities scores, and the 3rd method seems the best. If they are slightly different, that's understandable. If they are so different, which one should be used?

I like the result of the 3rd method, but it's extremely slow on both CPU and GPU machines when testing on these few sentences. The other 2 are much faster.

Comment: The question is, do you have any furthe training data? What is your downstream task? And why do you expect three (differently trained) models to return similar values?

Comment: @dennlinger I want to use the vectors as graph node's text features to compute node embedding.   The first 2 use the same model, but the way to compute the embedding is different. I suppose the cosine similarities based on different transformers or methods should be very similar, not a huge difference. In particular, one of the results should be more 'right' than other two. Otherwise, downstream tasks using the different embeddings will differ a lot in performance. Isn't it?